# can we position last step with first step position in flutter horizontal stepper when the horizontal overflow happens?

Tags: flutter, stepper

Hi I am very beginner to flutter  development I want to fix horizontal overflow issue in flutter stepper by changing position of the final steps. please If you know please help me to do that.

**Note: I can't use fa_stepper or im_stepper packages.**

This is the video link I followed to create this stepper https://youtu.be/nf4vn0SzkQc

[image]

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: You can use the ``Wrap`` widget.